# Toggle list-style-image via jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

How can i toggle the list-style-image via jQuery?

I first tried to change the list-style-image, but that won't work. Does anybody know what i'm doing wrong here?

```
[..]
$(this).closest('li').css("list-style-image","url('../Images/arrowDown.png')");
```

I also tried the following, but without the desired result

```
$(this).closest('li').css("list-style-image","url(arrowDown.png)");
```

and

```
$(this).closest('li').css({"list-style-image":"url(arrowDown.png)"});
```

Comment: Are you sure, the problem is with the `css()` part of your code? Does the selector work as you suspect?

Comment: I think it would be a much better idea to have difference css classes and switch between them rather than try and change the css directly with jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list-style-image` is set on the `ul`, so if you are trying to have the bullet image change on the hover, it will not work... each hover will trigger all the bullets switching.

If you want to change the bullets on the hover on each `li` then you need to add it as a `background-image`.  So something like this

```
$('li').hover(
    function(){
     $(this).removeClass('up').addClass('down');
    },
    function(){
     $(this).removeClass('down').addClass('up');
    }    
);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/SZzRm/

Answer (score 0):

You should `list-style-type` on the `ul`, not `li` element.

Try using camelCase on the css property. From [the docs on `.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

> Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. `margin`, `background`, `border`) are not supported.
>   For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin, use:
>   `$(elem).css('marginTop')` and `$(elem).css('marginRight')`, and so on.

So use:

```
$('ul').css('listStyleType', 'square');
```