# how to highlight text that has a list with an image bullet?

Tags: jquery

how to highlight only the (li) list of text that has a image bullet? How can I accomplish this.

```
           <ul>
                <li> test A </li>
                <li> test B </li>
                <li> test C </li>
           </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`list-style-image` is set on the `ul` <sup>*[[Check here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7471724/295264)*</sup> and correct way to define multiple word CSS is not like <sup>*[[moreinfo]](http://api.jquery.com/css/)*</sup>

```
$("ul").each(function(){
    if($(this).css("listStyleImage") != "") {
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/ZGDXu/)